# Passing context to a standard java class using getApplicationContext causes Force Close

Tags: android, applicationcontext, android-context

I am working on an android app and am currently having a problem with passing contexts to a standard Java class from a ListFragment.

I have a class called Common and in the constructor I pass the context so I can do various common tasks, such as displaying an alert dialogue, so that I can keep reusing the code instead of having to write the code out each time for every alert dialog box I need. To initialise the class in a standard activity I am using.

```
Common common = new Common(this);
```

The code above works fine if this is done in a class that extends an Activity. However, if I want to do the same sort of thing but in a class that extends a ListFragment, this doesn't work, so I use the following code in order initialise the class

```
Common common = new Common(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
```

When the above code is executed in the ListFragment, when a function is used to display a Yes/No alert dialogue I get a force close with the exception

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window
--token null is not for an application
```

Below is the code for the constructor for the class

```
public Common(Context context)
{
    this.context = context;
}
```

Just to reiterate, all of the functions within the Common class, including the Yes/No dialogue work fine without problems if the Common class is initialised from a class that extends **Activity** using the *this* argument passed to the constructor. Its only if I **getActivity().getApplicationContext()** as an argument passed to the constructor that I get this error.

As a test I have also changed one my classes that extends an activity and used the getApplicationContext instead of using this, and I get the same error, so its not necessarily specific to me using a ListFragment.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use `ApplicationContext` in your case. Instead use just `getActivity()`. Activity is a `Context` so your `Common` class constructor will be satisfied.

But your `Common` class should really have `Common(Activity a)` constructor instead.

Comment: Your half right, I do need to use getActivity() on its own not use getActivity().getApplicationContext(), but I didn't need to change the constructor for the common class to Activity, I've kept this as Context and its working fine, thanks for your help

Comment: @Boardy You didn't have to change the constructor, that's right. But if your constructor accepted Activities and not Contexts you wouldn't have had the problem in question.